# How to set hyperlink's target as "_self" after page has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, client-side-rendering

I have an InfoPath form including hyperlink on SharePoint page, when clicking the link, the page will be open in a new tab. I found in F12 that the link is made up like `<a class="dd_6buesmf8mnCnHLeF_0" href="https://..." target="_blank">`. Hence i wrote a very simple JS to update "_blank" to "_self" and updated in the Script Editor, but it seems to be fail to get all the links i want to customize when the page is loading. I suspect i must use SP.SOD to execute post loading action, can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntillScriptLoaded("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("da_6buesmf8mnCnHLeF_0");
alert(links.length);
for( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
alert(links[i].href +" "+links[i].target);
if(links[i].taget == "_top" || links[i].target=="_blank" ) 
{
alert(links[i].target);
links[i] = "_self";
}
}

      }
    });
  }

alert("init");
  init();

});
</script>
```